# How to profile embed firebird database

Tags: profiling, monitoring, firebird, profiler

Did I make wrong to use firebird database I don't know. It has lot's of good futures but I can't figure out why my query (stored procedure) didn't work.

Is there any profiler/monitoring tool for firebird?

Firebird database is working stand alone so it is embeded db. And It doesn't allow to connect with 2 users. If there is a profiler I wonder how it will connect while I'm executing my queries.

Comment: If the lack of ability to use other process to connect to the same database is stopping you to use a tool, do not use embedded in your development environment, you can install a (local) server and connect to it... and switch to embedded in your release version.

Comment: But I will deploy this db with windows form application. And the machines will use this application without network connection. Id on't want to install db server. That's why I want to use embedded db. Is mysql working without server?

Answer (score 1):

[IBExpert](http://www.ibexpert.com) and [Database Worbench](http://www.upscene.com) have stored procedure debugger

There is also many monitoring tools http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq95/

I advice you to install server version if you want to have more than 2 users